# Use a variable on two keyframes

Tags: flash

Is there a way to declare a variable on one key frame and then use and edit it in another?

I'm trying to declare a Boolean on one frame, which then acts as an if function for if something has been edited.

Frame 1:

```
var speedAdjust:Boolean = false;
var jumpAdjust:Boolean = false;

if(!speedAdjust){
    speedtxt.text = "Speed: 50";
}

if(!jumpAdjust){
    jumptxt.text = "Jump: 50";
}

speed.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, changespeed);
function changespeed(event:SliderEvent){
    speedtxt.text = "Speed: " + event.value;
    speedAdjust = true;
    maxSpeedConstant = event.value;
}

jump.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, changejump);
function changejump(event:SliderEvent){
    jumptxt.text = "Jump: " + event.value;
    jumpAdjust = true;
}
```

Frame 2:

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

jump.visible = false;
speed.visible = false;

speed.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, finalspeed);
function finalspeed(event:SliderEvent){
    maxSpeedConstant = event.value / 4;
    if(event.value <= 2){
        maxSpeedConstant = 1;
    }
    if(!speedAdjust){
    maxSpeedConstant = 12.5
    }
}

quit.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, exitRace);
function exitRace(event:MouseEvent){
    gotoAndStop(2);
    jump.visible = true;
    speed.visible = true;
}
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting a error message? Also, where did you declare the maxSpeedConstant variable?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you think you know what the problem with your code is (not being able to access a variable on a different frame) then forget your code for a second and try this code on a separate file:

Frame1:

```
var your_variable:Boolean = false;
```

Frame2:

```
trace(your_variable);
```

If this works than you know that the problem is not that you can't access the variable. Also remember that if the play head jumps to frame 2 your variable has not been declared.